# How to Create XIB/StoryBoard in Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-frameworks, ios-library

I am creating Framework so i want to create some view in framework itself but i am unable access created XIB/StoryBoard in Framework to any project.
If anybody worked on please help me to solve out.

Thanks..